# C++ Need thread safe wel tested containers (non microsoft)

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, containers

Any one having idea about thread safe data containers like queue, map?
I dont want threadsafe STL when we use /MT switches for compiler.

A real thread safe wel tested STL containers.

Comment: What do you mean by *I dont want threadsafe STL when we use /MT switches for compiler*?

Comment: If it is not clear enough from the previous sentence, what made you think that the STL would be thread-safe when using the /MT switch?

Comment: As ybungalobill points out there is an issue with what you mean by thread-safe containers. They do exist but their interfaces are not the same as STL: certain operations don't really make sense any more.

Answer (score 9):

Thread safe containers usually make no sense. Consider a 'thread-safe` queue:

```
if(!qu.empty())
{
    // 1
    qu.pop();
}
```

What if during #1 the queue is modified and it becomes empty? It breaks the code. This is why you should use locks in *your* code rather than 'thread-safe' containers.

Comment: +1 It is a really good point in bringing up that you cannot directly make a non-thread-safe container thread- safe by just adding locking to the implementation. A thread-safe container requires specific design, but it can be done with some changes in the interface: Substitute the `top/pop` by a single `void pop( T& v );` that throws if the queue is empty (or returns a boolean), allowing you to test for emptiness and return/throw, copy the value to the argument and remove the element from the container atomically (both thread and exception safe at once).

Comment: @David: yep, you can make a container with all the frequent operations atomic. You can make it for queue. However it restricts the interface significantly. For example you can't have iterators in map anymore!

Comment: While I agree with the basic sentiment there certainly are thread-sensitive containers. They tend to need slightly different APIs to be useful, but they have real purpose.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe: these are not "STL containers" the OP asked.

Answer (score 1):

[Intel TBB](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/) is specifically designed for this.

Comment: yes, looks good. has some std like thread-safe containers (concurrent_hash_map, concurrent_queue, concurrent_vector). But I see that is GPLv2. This means you should publish source-code ?

Answer (score 1):

/MT imply you want to link to multithreaded runtime library (which is compatible to multithreaded application), but it does not make the runtime library is thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Parallel Patterns Library (PPL) includes `concurrent_vector` and `concurrent_queue` and they added concurrent versions of `unordered_map`, `unordered_multimap`, `unordered_set`, and `unordered_multiset` to the Concurrency Runtime sample pack v0.33 and newer.